# How to fire enter button event dynamically using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an input it has a function running if the keycode ==13

I also have a button on the same page if the user clicks that button it should trigger click event associated with it and at the same time it should also fire the enter click using javascript

the code is shown as below

```
<input type="text" class="myInputValue">
<button class="myLink">submit</button>

(function(){
  var inputc = document.getElementsByClassName('myInputValue')[0];
  var submitbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('myLink')[0]
  inputc.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
      alert("Entered")
    }
  });
  submitbtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    // here I need functionality which will fire enter key event too

  });
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnq6xfwa/

Comment: `e.keyCode` is read-only, for good reasons. Why don't you just dispatch a `submit` event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Comment: Try reading this: [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: @connexo on the enter event is a global functionality so I don't want to disturb it. In only one case I want to trigger on submit so is there a way I can achieve the requirement

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to get the specific event data from the enter button being pressed and instead just need to same function to run you can give your anonymous function a name such as `processKey` and use that whenever you want the <kbd>enter</kbd> key code to run. Then when you click on your button, you can pass through `13` as the `key` argument to `processKey` method.

See working example below:

```js
function processKey(key) {
  if(key == 13){
    alert("Entered");
  }
}

(function(){
  var inputc = document.getElementsByClassName('myInputValue')[0];
  var submitbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('myLink')[0];
  
  inputc.addEventListener("keydown", e => processKey(e.keyCode));
  submitbtn.addEventListener("click", _ => processKey(13));
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" class="myInputValue">
<button class="myLink">submit</button>
```

Comment: the constrain hear is I cannot change the existing code. the only option I have is playing around with submit click event. is there a way which you can help

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom event and dispatch it.

```
submitbtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var event = new CustomEvent("keydown", {
        keyCode: 13
    });
    inputc.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Comment: Hi @shubham i have tried this but it is not working please find it in the link http://jsfiddle.net/pnq6xfwa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can call the btn event on enter.

```js
(function(){
  var inputc = document.getElementsByClassName('myInputValue')[0];
  var submitbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('myLink')[0]
  inputc.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
       submitbtn.click();
    }
  });
  submitbtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
 alert('Hello');

  });
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" class="myInputValue">
<button class="myLink">submit</button>
```

Or you can call function for both the events

```js
(function() {
  var inputc = document.getElementsByClassName('myInputValue')[0];
  var submitbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('myLink')[0]
  inputc.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      test();
    }
  });
  submitbtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    test();

  });
})();

function test(){
  alert('hello')
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="myInputValue">
<button class="myLink">submit</button>
```

Comment: the constrain hear is I cannot change the existing code. the only option I have is playing around with submit click event. is there a way which you can help

Comment: No, as I said I cannot make any changes to the function of input enter function